# Access to a directory in Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm writing a simple File Explorer application, This is what I have done so far:

```
 $window.requestFileSystem($window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
                    console.log("fs", fs);

                    var directoryReader = fs.root.createReader();

                    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                            var arr = [];
                            processEntries(entries, arr); // arr is pass by refrence
                            $scope.files = arr;
//                            $rootScope.hide();
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

The result of the above code just only allow me to access to the root directory of my phone.  However, I want to access to the specific folders in my phone. For example, I want to open the 'Download' folder everytime I open the app.  How can I get it to be done.  Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToYourDownloadDir)` ?

and be sure your are permission to acces file system